# why AI Training Custom Model on PC takes longer than my Laptop?

Tags: python, performance, visual-studio-code, scikit-learn

I'm making a custom training model for classification I tested the trained model on a PC with 2 CPU and 32 RAM with 4 G GPU but it's slower than Laptop 8 G Ram without GPU as shown on the screenshots My PC Takes almost 1 hour, my laptop takes 10 minutes so why is that?

This is the screen of my Laptop with windows 10
https://ibb.co/1zQn9Vm

This is the screen of my PC with windows 11
https://ibb.co/j8WTTL0

That is my code:

```
target = []
images =[]
flat_data =[]



DATADIR = r"Images"
CATEGORIES = ['cat1', 'cat2', 'cat3', 'cat4']

for cat in CATEGORIES:
class_num = CATEGORIES.index(cat)
path = os.path.join(DATADIR, cat)
for img in os.listdir(path):
  img2 = Image.open(os.path.join(path, img))
  compression_image = img2.info['compression']
  if(compression_image == 'group4'):
      img2.save(os.path.join(path, img), compression='tiff_lzw')                                                      
  img_array = imread(os.path.join(path, img))
  img_resized = resize(img_array, (200 , 200))
  flat_data.append(img_resized.flatten())
  images.append(img_resized)
  target.append(class_num)
  
  
 flat_data = np.array(flat_data)
 target = np.array(target)
 images = np.array(images)

 from sklearn.model_selection import  train_test_split
 x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test= train_test_split(flat_data, 
 target, test_size=0.3, random_state= 109)

 from sklearn.model_selection import  GridSearchCV
 from sklearn import svm

 param_grid = [
{'C': [1, 10, 100, 1000], 'kernel': ['linear']},
{'C': [1, 10, 100, 1000], 'gamma': [0.001, 0.0001], 'kernel': 
['rbf']}
]

svc = svm.SVC(probability= True)
clf = GridSearchCV(svc, param_grid)
clf.fit(x_train, y_train)
```

Comment: Could you provide extra information? Perhaps the code for your AI model? It's very difficult to see why your AI may be performing this way from CPU and memory info alone.

Comment: @Caeden I will edit my question and add the code for it

Comment: @Caeden can it be related to the Power supply? When I open the Task Manager I Can see VS code has very high power usage!

Comment: What about GPU usage? It doesn't appear that your code is taking advantage of GPU acceleration.

Comment: @Caeden I didn't get what you mean? but I take snapshots from my GPU from the task manager https://ibb.co/zJSf1vw

Comment: As a parameter to GridSearchCV try setting n_jobs=-1. This will use all of the cores on your CPU which should give you a performance boost.

Comment: @Caeden It works really ran the code at 2 minutes instead of 40 minutes Thanks brooo

Comment: @Caeden last question please, I have 40 CU on my PC so what is the best n_jobs I can use? I made it 8 and finished my code at 2.39 mins instead of 40 mins without destroying my CPU

Comment: The best n_jobs value is -1. By default, an n_jobs value of -1 uses all CPU cores.

Comment: @Caeden  n_jobs value is -1 won't destroy my pc?

Comment: It shouldn't unless your CPU doesn't have proper cooling. I would suggest keeping an eye on your CPU temperature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After I added this parameter It works well.

```
GridSearchCV try setting n_jobs=-1
```